# go to top button not visible in chromium after fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am facing very strange problem.

when i am using page down or fragmented identifier to jump to some div,at that time my go to top image is not visible.

here is my code.

html:

```
<a title="Go to top" href="#" class="back-to-top"></a>
```

less(css):

```
.back-to-top {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50%;
right: 15px;
text-decoration: none; 
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 1em;
display: none;
background-image: url("/images/go-top.png");
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
```

}

javascript:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(600);
    } 
    else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(600);
    }
});

$('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Where is `duration` being set?

Comment: its variable with value 600

Comment: If you can post the entire script I can try to debug it rather then giving you a new one like all the rest below.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/zxHxD/)

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('.back-to-top').hide();

    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/zxHxD/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.back-to-top').hide();
    var test = 1;
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if (test == 1) {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                    $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
                }
                test = 2;
            } else if (test == 2) {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
                    $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
                }
                test = 1;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: same problem with chrome.